# What are all these comments I see on HTML pages after the doctype?

Tags: html, conditional-statements, doctype

Can anyone tell me what this is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->  <html class="no-js iframe" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

I have seen this on so many pages but there is no JavaScript link on some of the pages to support the document declaration.

Comment: “there is no JavaScript link on some of the pages to support the document declaration.” — I don’t quite understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be snippet from html5 Boilerplate's standard format for 'browser detection' , see http://html5boilerplate.com/

The section that you have highlighted allows for only one section of the `<html>` tag to be parsed depending upon the flavour of browser that the site visitor is using.

Read more about this method at the authors website > http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: Thank you. Someone who understood. Marked and repped.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <!--[if lt IE 7]>
```

That means that code inside the `<!--[if lt IE 7]>...<![endif]-->` will work only in IE 7 browser
and `<!--[if lt IE 8]>...<![endif]-->` only in IE8 browsers

This hint working only in IE browsers. For example you can write `<!--[if lt IE 7]><style .../><![endif]-->` and this style will work only in IE 7. Than on the next line you can write `<!--[if lt IE 8]><style .../><![endif]-->` and this styles will work only in IE8

Answer (score 2):

This is the doctype for HTML5 pages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The following lines means that the code between the commented tags is IE specific (first one is for browsers less than IE7 (IE6, IE5, etc...), second one for IE7, third one for IE8 and the last one for >= IE9)

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->  <html class="no-js iframe" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: How many patronising replies. Maybe it was how I worded it.. so IE simply cannot use the normal <!DOCTYPE html> and instead has to resort to the normal conditional statements of which I am already aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Those are only checks for compatibility with older browsers

`<!DOCTYPE html>` usually refers to HTML5, browsers below IE9 don't support HTML5 at all, so tweaks are needed. That's why there are HTML if-clauses that check if you use IE and which version. The HTML element gets a special class for that browser version so that CSS can see if it's IE and in which version (e.g. for fixing the box model of IE6)

The no-js class probably gets removed by JavaScript so that CSS can access specific elements only if JavaScript is on/off

Answer (score 0):

You should use this as your Doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

The rest is not relevant for the doctype, and is IE-specific.